# Which logic to use for loop. Easiest vs most efficient

Tags: powershell, active-directory

As I am not an expert programmer, which logic should I use for easy to understand, but efficient script?  I am writing a script that searches all AD users and based on an AD attribute(ie office), it'll write some strings to few other attributes (city, postal code, etc).  I've been playing around with Foreach and then within that loop using either set-ADUser with replace or where clause.  Or the very messy way of a bunch of IF, IfElse  statements.  Also, I started looking at Switch (Case) statements.

Any suggestions?

Starting small to build upon it, I started with this:

```
 $Users = Get-ADUser -searchbase "OU=users,OU=testing,DC=blah,DC=company,DC=com" -filter {samaccountname -like "r*"} -properties * | Select samaccountname,streetaddress,l, postalcode,st,physicaldeliveryofficename
foreach ($user in $users) {
set-aduser $user -city "NoWhere" -Postalcode "B2B 2B2"| where {$_.physicaldeliveryofficename -eq "Head Office"} 
}
```

Or a switch instead:

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -searchbase "OU=users,OU=testing,DC=blah,DC=company,DC=com" -filter {samaccountname -like "remot*"} -properties * | Select samaccountname,streetaddress,l, postalcode,st,physicaldeliveryofficename
foreach ($user in $users) {switch ($users.physicaldeliveryofficename){
"Nowhere town" { -city "NoWhere" -postalcode "A1A A1A"}
"Anywhereville" { -city "Anywhere" -postalcode "B1B B1B"}
}}
```

Comment: it depends on the script a lot of times. Usually readability is much more important than raw performance however.

Comment: PowerShell isn't SQL, `Set-ADUser ... | where Office = 'Head Office'` is meaningless in powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Optimize the query because querying complex external resources usually takes 99% of runtime.
2. Use pipelining so that processing starts *immediately* without accumulating the entire list:
   instead of `ForEach` statement use `| ForEach { ......... }`.
3. Stop writing oneliners: you can start a new line after `|`, `(`, `{`, `,`, unfinished two-operand operators like `+` or use a single backtick ` at the end of line to wrap long lists of parameters.
4. `Switch` is the way to go here because when pipelining there's no entire list available so each element should be processed individually.

```
Get-ADUser -searchbase "OU=users,OU=testing,DC=blah,DC=company,DC=com" `
           -filter 'samaccountname -like "r*"' `
           -properties * |
    Select samaccountname,
           streetaddress,
           l,
           postalcode,
           st,
           physicaldeliveryofficename |
    ForEach {
        switch ($_.physicaldeliveryofficename) {
            "Nowhere town"  { $city = "NoWhere"; $postalcode = "A1A A1A"; break }
            "Anywhereville" { $city = "Anywhere"; $postalcode = "B1B B1B"; break }
            default         { $city = "?"; $postalcode = "" }
        }
        Set-ADUser $_ -City $city -Postalcode $postalcode
    }
```

Comment: Why nest a loop in a loop? `Switch (Get-ADUser <args>){{$_.physicaldeliveryofficename -match "Nowhere"}{Set-ADUser $_ -City "Nowhere";Continue};{$_.physicaldeliveryofficename -match "Anywhere"}{Set-ADUser $_ -City "Anywhere";Continue}}`. And I'd argue point 3 a bit, there's a happy medium between what you posted and what the OP has, but neither are great in my opinion.

Comment: 1. There's no nested loop because `switch` isn't really a loop. As for your example, it doesn't utilize pipeline: it fetches the entire list of users first so there could be a very long pause. In case only one simple action need to be performed your approach might be better though. 2. There's no need to argue about #3, it's just common sense and personal preference. I'm also guilty of writing oneliners but those are for write-once write-only scripts.

Comment: That is not correct, it does not fetch the entire list of users first. It will get users, and evaluate each user against the `Switch` statement as each result is received. Also, it is a loop, which is why the `Continue` statement works on it to move to the next user found.

Comment: Switch does not pipeline according to a simple reliable test: `switch(gci c:\* -recurse) { {$_.fullname -like '*'} { 1 } }` - I see a long pause, and it would be quite strange if pipelining could be invoked other than via `|`. As for `switch` being a loop, I concede the point as your arguments are convincing. Nevertheless, it does not defeat my primary point which is the use of pipeline.